# Saving data to model via other model

Tags: django

I have two models that look like this:

```
class Responde(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
        responde = models.ForeignKey(Responde, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I have a script that parse xml files or file-like objects. Than I save xml data to the database.

```
for p in products_xml:
   xmldata = Product()
   xmldata.name = p['ProductName']
   xmldata.description = p['ProductDescription']
   xmldata.price = p['ProductPrice']

   xmldata.save()
```

And everything works fine. But I need to create Responde object and than save data in to the Product model via Responde object. I tried to do it using this code

```
 for p in products_xml:
    r = Responde()
    name = p['ProductName']
    hotelcode = p['ProductDescription']
    country = p['ProductPrice']
    new_responde = r.product_set.create(name, description, price)
```

but i have error:

```
create() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

What i did wrong? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for creating a new `Product` is correct. After creating a `Responde` object, you can set it as the foreign key for your product.

```
# create a Responde object
r = Responde.objects.create() 

for xmldata in products_xml:
    p = Product(
        name=xmldata['ProductName'],
        description=xmldata['ProductDescription'],
        price=xmlData['ProductPrice'],
    )

    # add product to responde "r"
    p.responde = r
    p.save()

# this queryset contains all the products added above
r.product_set.all()
```